# Emulator is not install (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sdk, installation, emulation

> I downloaded android studio. Due to this error, I have repeatedly
>   erased and reloaded. Because the emulator was never installed. I'm
>   following these steps to create a virtual machine;

```
Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Create Virtual Devices
```

> I choose what to choose. But on the right is "no emulator installed".
>   And below it side "install emulator". I'm clicking on this button. But
>   nothing changed.It looks like its loading but it doesn't.
>
> What should I do? Would you please help me ?

Comment: Please explain in a simple language what you want to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Edit you question with what OS (Windows 7/10,Mac, Linux (distro please)) along with CPU (Intel/AMD, 32bit/64bit).

Comment: The real problem i can't install emulator. I tried to install Genymotion. But it wants me to buy that license key. And my OS is win10.